# Posting directly to Facebook Wall over Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, facebook-graph-api

I want to post to my Facebook User walldirectly from my Google App Engine application.
I found a solving that:
http://komunitasweb.com/2011/07/how-to-programmatically-post-to-facebook-wall/

This solve works in normal python console application but when i using in Google App Engine Project it isn't work because Google App Engine can't find some functions in urllib.

Is there any solving for this problem. I have

Comment: "Can't find some function in urllib" - what function? Please include your code and the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

All Google App Engine applications run in a restrictive environment. There you can't use certain native python libraries. The best option is to use the apis Google provides such as the urlfetch api. And you should test your applications locally using App Engine sdk for Python.

You may use the [facebook-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/python-sdk) libray and checkout the sample GAE application from [here](https://github.com/facebook/python-sdk/tree/master/examples/appengine)